# rotating svg elements around center

Tags: animation, svg, rotation, transform

What am I doing wrong to rotate around center

I set transform-origin of each  is right in the center of square

Look here pls
    https://jsfiddle.net/yqx90or9/1/

```
group.style.transformOrigin = '100px 100px'
group.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
transition: all 1s linear 1s;
```

When you change the style, you are changing the `transform`, but you are also changing the `transform-origin`.  So both get animated. The result is your weird behaviour.  Change it to:

```
transition: transform 1s linear 1s;
```